# unpack .tar.gz files only (Node.js)

Tags: node.js

please help me solve the problem correctly. i have example.tar.gz file.
has the following nesting:

```
-folder1
     --folder1_1
       ---file.json
-folder2
     --folder2_2
       ---file2.json
```

...and so on...
what is the best way to save only files in a folder and which library do you think should be used?
only files from the archive should be saved to the server, regardless of the number of subfolders, the name of the folders can be anything.
result:

```
/tmp/file.json file2.json file3.json ...
```

thanks in advance for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, I made it through the decompress.js library.

```js
try {
  decompress('tmp/json.tar.gz', 'tmp/decompress', {
    map: (file, index) => {
      file.path = `${index}_${file.path.split('/').splice(-1).join('/')}`
      return file
    }
  }).then(files => {
    console.log(files)
    return res.json({ data: true })
  })
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```